# Is there a (simple) way to "curl" an external URL in a JSP Page?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, curl, wget

Our Organisation's web branding changed, so when serving up a `CGI` page we first `curl` a template (prepared / updated by our marketing team).  We aren't a `Tomcat/Java shop`, but have a need to deploy and brand a Tomcat webapp.

Currently the main JSP page consists of static HTML with inline JSP calls (e.g. `<%= request.getContextPath()%>)`.

What is the simplest way to `wget` / `curl` from within a JSP page so that we can apply our branding ?

In Python we would do something along the lines of:

```
template_url = 'http://url/to/our/template.php'
req = urllib2.Request(template_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
txt = response.read()
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JSTL's [`<c:import tag>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html):

> Retrieves an absolute or relative URL and exposes its contents to
>   either the page, a String in 'var', or a Reader in 'varReader'.